# Viewpager doesn't update current page

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have a Gridview in all page inside ViewPager. When I try to load  the images in gridview  in all page, it doesn't updated the current page because problably ViewPager caches the recent views. So when I navigate to further pages, I can see the changes. How can I make the current page show the changes. Thanks...